# I am working in camel (Servicemix 5.4.0) i am getting below error message for sql in pom

Tags: java, sql, apache-camel, pom.xml, apache-servicemix

I am working in `camel` (Servicemix 5.4.0) i am getting below error message while compiling project using `mvn install`

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver:sqljdbc4:jar:4.0: Failure to find
com.microsoft.sqlserver:sqljdbc:jar:4.0.2206.100 in https://repo.maven.apache.or
g/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted
until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
```

I think it might because of pom.xml dependency part.
I have given following dependency in `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
<artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
<version>4.0</version>
<scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Please Help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This driver is not in **Maven standard repository.**

You could download it, and add to you local repository with:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=sqljdbc4.jar -DgroupId=com.microsoft.sqlserver -DartifactId=sqljdbc4 -Dversion=4.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```

---

Download link for the driver:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11774

Comment: Thanks alot :) its working now  but when i run the command "features:install camel-sql-orders"  in ServiceMix  its giving error            "Error executing command: No feature matching camel-sql-orders/0.0.0"  Please Help me how to resolve that

Comment: Now it's a serviceMix error...
Since I'm not an expert, you should open another question thread for this... :-(